# Installation Issue in Smart Device CAB Project

Tags: windows-mobile, cab

we are creating a package for smart device CAB project, which has satellite assemblies. hough we are new to this, after successful installation when application is trying to access the  set of satellite assemblies we are getting "Missing resource manifest" exception, but when we replace the culture specific folder or satellite assemblies manually inside the smart device application will work fine.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem after installing my application's CAB file. This issue generally occurs when the resource files for a language are wrongly copied to some other language folder e.g. the en_US resource files are copied to da_DK folder. Please verify this in your project responsible for making the .CAB file for your mobile device, you might be adding wrong language file assemblies in your project's 'Application Folder'.

You can also test buy temporarily deleting all language resources folders from Application Folder except en-US and deploy on your device. This should work.

Hope this helps !!!

Cheers,
Rajesh